# How to distinguish Empty cells from Zero

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to count a number of specific responses from a form where the response can be left empty, zero or any other number 'd'.

The following code:

```
var data = sheet.getRange("B2:L").getValues();

var d = 0;
if (data[i][j] == d){
    count++;
}
```

assumes that `an empty cell == 0` is true, thus counting the wrong number of cells that actually hold the value zero

```
var d = 0;
if (data[i][j] != '' && data[i][j] == d){
    count++;
}
```

or any variation with `!= null / != ""` does not seem to work for me

EDIT : [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArGBxqJcwGSCdDhUcTE3M25ZUkRpb25ibURfcUZ0OVE) to document. I think you can see the script if you make a copy.

Comment: Can you share a doc with us?

Comment: Added the complete code (at least the counting part) will be helpful as well. Can you edit your question?

Comment: Added a link to my document.. hope you're able to see the script.

Comment: Nicely styled sheet you have created !! I will take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When counting for the different `d` values, you need to check whether the objects in the array are `string` or `number` based:

```
for (var j=1; j<lastColumn-1; j++) {
  if (typeof data[i][j] !== 'string') {
    count[+data[i][j]][d]++;   
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfect! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isBlank()) function?

Comment: OP is after a script solution.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra, `isBlank()` is a Google Apps Script function (Check the link).

Comment: @Punchlinern Didn't know that...

Comment: You learn something everyday :)

Comment: @phermous: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following to determine empty, zero-value or 'else'.

```
 if (cell === "") // empty cell
     doEmptyCellStuff();
 else
 if (cell == 0)  // zero-value cell
     doZeroValueCellStuff();
 else
     dValueCellStuff();
```

Comment: The title doesn't correspond to the problem faced. I had to dig in deep to understand real problem. This isn't resolving the problem

Comment: Why not? Seems like it will correctly skip empty cells. It's just that doEmptyCellStuff should be a no-op in the OP's case... and the last else can be left off.